# How to control Play/stop video texture in Blend4web?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, blend4web

I want to control play/stop behavior of a video texture applied over a 'Plane' mesh.

I searched for it on the Blend4web forum but unfortunately did not find any easy solution. However, there are some solutions, which directs towards some projects, but these projects use a lot of javascript code and are non-understandable to me.

By default, we can apply a video texture to a mesh and it will loop infinitely. We cannot stop/pause or replay it.

Does anyone has idea how to do it?

Comment: You should probably be asking this over at the [Blend4Web Forum](https://www.blend4web.com/en/forums). It also sounds like you already know the answer to your question: Do it with Javascript coding!

Comment: No, I don't. I am newbie. Anyway, I am trying to find the solution anyway.